# How is Cisco able to Vibe about an event which didn't happen in this timeline in Cause and XS?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In the latest episode of ***The Flash***, S05E14, Nora time travels 52 times to save *xyz* person. It's good that Nora is taking charge to save the world and all while Barry is away.

Now, my question is- How did Cisco, *aka Vibe* sees his date with Kamilla which didn't happen in that timeline yet?

Cisco's Power can breach through the multiverse, *agreed*. But can he also **Time-Travel?**

Here is a wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibe_(comics))

> His powers can affect the physical world as seismic vibration (and even earth manipulation), or the fabric of spacetime (interdimensional, transdimensional and extradimensional portals).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know from Season 1 that Cisco can vibe timelines that just got changed. This happened when he remembered a timeline where he was killed by Reverse Flash, timeline that was altered by Barry traveling to the past for the first time. From the *[arrow wikia](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Cisco_Ramon)*,

> Cisco questioned Wells, who told him the truth - that his name was Eobard Thawne and he was trapped in the past, needing Barry to gain enough speed to return him to the future. He told Cisco that he actually liked him, before he killed him. However, Cisco was brought back to life when Barry accidentally traveled back in time and used his knowledge of the future to change it. **Cisco would later remember that alternate timeline by using his powers.**

Barry's time travel happens in the episodes *Out of Time* and *Rogue Time*, and this video shows Cisco remembering his murder in a previous timeline:

(from the episode *All Star Team Up*)

**Note**: the link provided in the OP is about the comics, and the show adapts the source material more or less closely as it sees fit.